# Bootstrap Carousel is jumping because height of text is not equal to corresponding card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am haveing some trouble with the carousel class in bootstrap. I copied most of this code directly from w3 schools and then have modified a bit to fit my needs. The issue I am having is that when the second slide is of a different height than the section title the screen will jump.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container text-center my-3">
  <div class="row mx-auto my-auto align-items-center">
    <div id="educationCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item py-5 active">
          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-10 align-center">
              <div class="card-transparent">
                <div class="card-body sectionHeaderTitle">
                  <p class="card-title display-3">Section title</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item py-5">
          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-10 align-center">
              <div class="card card-overlay">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h1 class="card-title">Section Title</h1>
                  <p class="card-body">info
                    <br> some more info
                    <br> asdf
                    <br>
                    <br> asdf asdf a fasdf asfd fas df
                    <br>
                    <br>asdf afsd f asd fasfd fasfasdfas
                    <br> asdf asf f as sfd f </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#educationCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span><img src="../data/Arrows/leftArrow.png"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#educationCarousel" data-slide="next" data toggle="popover" title="Click Me!" data-content="Click here to see more information about Stuart's education">
        <span><img src="../data/Arrows/rightArrow.png"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm assuming that if the heights are the same the screen will not jump. The issue lies in the fact that it's text vs a card. Does anybody know how to set the height of the text div to be the same as it's corresponding card? Or is there some other solution I have not been able to find?

Note: My CSS file does not touch the functionality of any object within this bit of code.

Comment: Where is the CSS to your project?

Comment: As I said I have no custom CSS on this section so posting it is unnecessary